# Vuex - How to create a global variable in store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, global-variables, vuex

Is it possible to have a global variable in store? I want to create/remove an interval I use for polling an API. Right now I do the following:

```
const refreshData = null;

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        ...
    },
    mutations: {
        ...
    },
    actions: {
        pollForData() {
            // Make API call
            .
            .
            .
            // Set interval to poll every 5 seconds if the data has a certain flag
            if(res.data.update) {
                if(!refreshData) {
                    refreshData = setInterval(() => {
                        dispatch('pollForData');
                    });
                }
            } else {
                if(refreshData) {
                    clearInterval(refreshData);
                    refreshData = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, but the variable lying outside is bothering me. Because I don't know if this is the right way to do it, and I think there must be a better way.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have variables outside of the store. What you probably need to change is the fact that polling shouldn't be don from the store. You can move the code in a different service and just feed data in the store.

Comment: Understood, I have faced issues in the past with having too much logic in the store. Maybe I should move it away to my component. Thanks.